# Is it possible to disable/remove a middleware for specific route in ExpressJS?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to disable a specific middleware, which I've set up previously in the app.js, for example:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

And then I want to remove that *bodyParser()* for a specific route for instance:

```
app.post("/posts/add", Post.addPost);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You could write a function to detect a condition, like this:

```
function maybe(fn) {
    return function(req, res, next) {
        if (req.path === '/posts/add' && req.method === 'POST') {
            next();
        } else {
            fn(req, res, next);
        }
    }
}
```

And then modify the app.use statement:

```
app.use(maybe(express.bodyParser()));
```

Comment: This helped me out as well, we have custom middlewear that we use globally with app.use, and now we want it disabled for certain routes.  The solution we came up with was to make the middlewear accept a list of routes is shouldn't act upon :D niceeeeeeeeeee

Answer (score 0):

In typescript, you might write an `except` function like so:

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction, } from 'express';
type MiddlewareFn = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => void;

export const middlewareExcept =
    (fn: MiddlewareFn, except: string[]): MiddlewareFn =>
    (req, res, next) => {
        if (except.includes(req.path)) next();
        else fn(req, res, next);
    };
```

```
app.use(middlewareExcept(authz, ["/public"]));
```