# Disable authentication middleware for specific verb on specific route

Tags: javascript, authentication, express, web

I am using Express/Node and have written some authentication middleware to check JWT on every request.

I would like to disable this middleware for the route (POST '/api/user/')however I want to keep the middleware for the route (GET '/api/user/').

How can I achieve this?

Please see code below.

**app.js**

```
// app.js


app.use('/api/userauth', require('./Controllers/api/userauth.js'))
app.use(require('./Middleware/Authenticate.js'));
app.use('/api/user', require('./Controllers/Api/User.js'));
app.use('/api/item', require('./Controllers/Api/Item.js'));
```

**authenticate.js**

```
//authenticate.js middleware


    var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];


    if (token) {
        jwt.verify(token, secretKey.secretKey, function(err, decoded){
            if (err) {
                return res.json({
                    success : false,
                    message : "failed to auth token."
                })
            } else {
                console.log(decoded);
                req.decoded = decoded;
                next();
            }
        })
    } else {
        res.status(403).send({
            success:false,
            message:'no token provided'
        })
    }
}
```

**api/user.js**

```
router.route('/')

.get(function(req,res){
    models.User.findAll({
    }).then(function(users){
        res.json(users);
    })
})

.post(function(req,res){
    models.User.create({
        username : req.body.username,
        password : req.body.password,
        firstname : req.body.firstname,
        lastname : req.body.lastname
    }).then(function(user){
        res.json({
            "Message" : "Succesfully created user: ",
            "User: " : user
        });
    });
});
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: somelike this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19337446/is-it-possible-to-disable-remove-a-middleware-for-specific-route-in-expressjs

Comment: @LucasCosta Great that works! thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Old issue but here you go!

Instead of using a blank

```
app.use(require('./Middleware/Authenticate.js'));
```

for all routes just do this in your sub routers

**api/user.js**

```
var authMiddleware = require('./Middleware/Authenticate.js')
router.route('/')

.get(function(req,res){
    models.User.findAll({
    }).then(function(users){
        res.json(users);
    })
})

.post(authMiddleware, function(req,res){
    models.User.create({
        username : req.body.username,
        password : req.body.password,
        firstname : req.body.firstname,
        lastname : req.body.lastname
    }).then(function(user){
        res.json({
            "Message" : "Succesfully created user: ",
            "User: " : user
        });
    });
});
module.exports = router;
```

Now it's just that route that has the Authenticate Middleware not the get one!